# Getting an internal server error on an inherited Craft 3 site

Tags: craft3, error-message, hosting

I was asked to host a Craft site, my client knows I've never done it before and is letting me explore a bit.  The file that were sent over were customized, so I'm mucking through it.

I uploaded the files that were sent.

In the files that they transferred there was no .env so I created it based on the env.example.  I added the, set the site URL to the IP address of the new hosting, set the right database creds and uploaded the db.

When I loaded that, I just got a white screen.  I noticed there was no vendor directory though, so I uploaded that directory and now I am getting a white screen with the error "An internal server error occurred."

I looked in my storage/logs/phperror.log and it says this:

```
[20-Dec-2023 05:14:51 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught yii\base\InvalidConfigException: The "id" configuration for the Application is required. in /storage/av/www/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php:218
Stack trace:
#0 /storage/av/www/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(200): yii\base\Application->preInit()
#1 [internal function]: yii\base\Application->__construct()
#2 /storage/av/www/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(419): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs()
#3 /storage/av0/www/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(170): yii\di\Container->build()
#4 /storage/av/www/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(365): yii\di\Container->get()
#5 /storage/av/www/public_html/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/Craft.php(53): yii\BaseYii::createObject()
#6 /storage/av/www/public_html/vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/bootstrap.php(251): Craft::createObject()
#7 /storage/av/www/public_html/vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/web.php(40): require('/storage/av0936...')
#8 /storage/av/www/public_html/web/index.php(11): require('/storage/av0936...')
#9 {main}
  thrown in /storage/av/www/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php on line 218
```

Other notes...
The Assets are on an AWS account.  I believe I have that setup correctly, but I can't get in to the dashboard to see.

I didn't run any setup for craft and the hosting that we are testing with says composer is installed, but I haven't tried anything with it.

I still have access to the actual live site as well. (and it is working)